# How to exclude ligatures from hyphenation, if their constituent characters have non-zero lccode?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

Is there some trick to make LuaTeX hyphenate ``xxaaxx'' in the following example?

```
\language255
\righthyphenmin=2
\lefthyphenmin=2
\hyphenation{xx-aa-xx}
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=1pt
\hfuzz=100pt
\lccode`\'=`\'
\hskip0pt ``xxaaxx''
\bye
```

Comment: the ligature isn't that relevant really is it? you see essentially the same  with `\`xxaaxx'` where no ligatures are involved.  but you also need to say what other constraints you have as most methods would be equivalent to removing the lccode line, which is presumably there only so that `'` is considered a letter for hyphenation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the single `'` must behave as a letter (because in some languages it *is* a letter). The only place where it must not is `''`, and as this is ligature, I thought that this may be the hook by means of which we can suppress this "letter" meaning **automatically** (if luatex will let to do this somehow), using the fact that ligature is actually a separate character (`'042`) with zero lccode

Comment: ah OK I see, you could use the pre-hyphenation callback to insert something invisible before the double quote, but that seems a bit heavy handed, ...

Comment: It hyphenates if you use `\hyphenation{xx-aa-xx''}`, which looks rather logical as the "word" is not xxaaxx. With pdftex you get the same (but there the extended hyphenation must go after the lccode). With xetex your example hyphenates directly -- probably xetex process first the ligatures.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer actually the request seems reasonable think of italian which makes ' part of the word by changing lccode but you want to put a word in double quotes and still be considered for hyphenation,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I didn't try to comment the request, only making some observations. But I think that these "fake" ligatures are difficult to handle (even more in luatex). I personally never used this ligature quotes. In older days I had as a german "` and "', nowadays I use csquotes and \enquote or Autoquotes like „“ or  «».